# Show text without alert when no checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have this js, but is working just when i delete de "nothing" field, but is ugly in my site if not showme couse i have no checkbox cheked.

js:

```
setInterval(function(){
   section[0].innerHTML = '';
   for(var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++){
     if(checkbox[i].checked){
     section[0].innerHTML += checkbox[i].value;        
     } else {
     section[0].innerHTML = 'nothing';
     }
   }
 }, 10);
```

html

```
Checked checkbox: <b><section></section></b>
```

This js is woking fine, but i wanna add nothing field:

```
setInterval(function(){
   section[0].innerHTML = '';
   for(var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++){
     if(checkbox[i].checked){
     section[0].innerHTML += checkbox[i].value;        
     }
   }
 }, 10);
```

Comment: Wait, why aren't you using `onchange` event for checkboxes???

Comment: Your name opened a bug for stackoverflow team. They now need to use ellipsis to show large text.

Comment: BTW, this is just invalid HTML markup: `<b><section></section></b>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that nothing is not an option, and that you want to write "nothing" if non of the boxes are selected. In that case this should work.

```
setInterval(function(){
   section[0].innerHTML = '';
   var nothing = true;
   for(var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++){
       if(checkbox[i].checked){
           section[0].innerHTML += checkbox[i].value;
           nothing = false;
       }
   }
   if(nothing){
        section[0].innerHTML = 'nothing';
   }

 }, 10);
```